# Xcode for app approval by Apple

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode7

I have a rather long app, about 20 pages and some of the code should probably be re-coded, my first app with Xcode and I learned a lot along the way. I could add a few objects to replace string arrays etc and make the code more readable. I was wondering if Apple looks at all the code when submitting to the app store or if they just want it to work with no errors. So I guess the question is ... should I 'fix' my code before submitting it?

Comment: Do you know the difference between source and binary?

Comment: When the app submits to test flight I have no idea what it's doing. It could upload the code for apple to look at. I never submitted an app before so I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Apple can access your code unless they can decode your binary app back to source somehow (It is very difficult to do that). They do perform some testings on your binary project (such as networking) and play around your app a little bit to check if your function provided is valid and works as described without any serious bug.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your app works and does not violate any of the App Store Review Guidelines you should be fine, you can check the Review guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality) to get more information about the review process and what Apple expects from your app.